# TransformException duplicate entry for common.annotations.Beta

Tags: java, android, dependencies, duplicates, android-gradle-plugin

This started when I added `google-api-services-calendar`. I am getting this error when trying to build:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
     com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: 
     duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class
```

This is part of the output when running `./gradlew app:dependencies`:

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0
|                   \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.1.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.1.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0 (*)
+--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
+--- com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4
+--- com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0
|    \--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0
|         +--- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.20.0
|         |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0
|         |    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|         |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|         +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.20.0
|         |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.3 -> 2.2.2
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:13.0
+--- com.android.support:design:23.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1
+--- com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1 (*)
+--- com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1
|    \--- com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.3.1
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.2
|         |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.2
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.2
|         \--- com.firebase:tubesock:0.0.11
+--- com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.3.0 -> 2.3.1 (*)
+--- net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.0
|    \--- joda-time:joda-time:2.8
+--- org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.5
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0
\--- com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3
     \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1 (*)
```

**I have tried adding this to *all* my dependencies:**

```
compile (some.dependencie.that.may.or.may.not.have.the.duplicate){
    exclude group: 'com.google.common', module: 'annotations'
}
```

**I tried adding this to my `android` block:**

```
configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'com.google.common', module: 'annotations'
}
```

with these variations:

```
 all*.exclude module: 'annotations`
 all*.exclude group: 'com.google.common'
 all*.exclude group: 'com.google.common.annotations'
```

**This is the `build.gradle` *before* any attempts to fix error:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Google
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }

    // Android Design
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'

    // Android Support
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }

    // Firebase
    compile('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile('com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }

    // Joda Time
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.0'
    compile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.2'

    // Square
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    // Common
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'

    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
}
```

I have searched my project for `Beta.class` and found that it is only being used in some jars; `com.google.common.annotations`, `com.google.api.client.util` and `dagger.internal`. I tried to add the `exclude group` to those related dependencies and still see the same error.

I have been stuck here for way too long. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just faced this problem when updating the Android Gradle plugin to com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3. In my case, the problem is due to AndroidSlidingUpPanelLayout, which depends in turn on nineoldandroids ([link](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=nineoldandroids)), and it produces the error. I "fixed" it going back to com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0.

Comment: I am still on 1.3.0 and havent changed since it came out.

Comment: @ChadBingham Can you try to also exclude `com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:13.0` module; And then, run the task again?

Comment: @kucing_terbang expand on that, exclude guava from what module? or exclude what from guava?

Comment: @ChadBingham from `google-api-services-calendar` module.

Comment: Hi @ChadBingham I've tried to compile sample project with your dependencies list and it works fine on 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3' and 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'.  I even don't have app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug task in gradle build tasks. It seems that problem in you build.gradle file. Have you tried to build simple project just with these dependencies?

Comment: @Alexandr yes i tried it in a different project and it worked, UNTIL I added manifest permissions for google Calendar API. then I say the same error.

Comment: @kucing_terbang i tried this and saw the same error.

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40938643/2107661) to resolve this error in general.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Exclude `group: 'com.google.guava'` from play services related dependencies.

For example:

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

P.S. Before getting your error I've faced with a lot of different, so my final dependencies list is:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Google
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'

    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev125-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }

    // Android Design
    compile ('com.android.support:design:23.0.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    // Android Support
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    // Firebase
    compile('com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile('com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }

    // Joda Time
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.0'
    compile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.2'

    // Square
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    // Common
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'

    compile ('com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why was **guava** specifically the one that needed to be excluded?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, I've tried to exclude guava intuitively. And guava was really a problem. I have no clue why...

Comment: I've the same problem. I have used the same library in `libs` folder as well as in gradle dependency. I removed in one place and problem is gone.

Comment: I found removing my reference to guava simpler
    //compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'

Comment: I got  'duplicate entry: com/google/api/client/util/ArrayMap$Entry.class'

Comment: @ImanMarashi, @SuperBale try to run `./gradlew app:dependencies` and check the output

Comment: I had the same error. I imported a new library that contained an older version of guava but I have imported the newest version of guava before that. At debug compile I got this error: "Duplicate zip entry guava-jdk5-17.0.jar...". I excluded guava from the new imported library compile and it solved the problem. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I had different versions of play services libs in my app module and a library module.

Comment: Great! only this answer solved my issue, thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason to be the incorrectly configured `dagger-compiler`:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1'
```

What I had done is to modify project' build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```

And later the application build.gradle:

First, add plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

And later modify the dependency to:

```
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1"
```

Comment: I had the same issue, had one entry:
  apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1'
and then another:
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1'
Getting rid of the *compile* entry solved the TransformException for me.