# zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: annotations/Beta.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been struggling for more that a day to fix the duplicate entry given when running my android project.

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class
```

I've tried to exclude various modules as well as enable multiDex, and have hit a wall, please help me solve this problem:

part of code:

```
 compile(project(path: ':k_endpoint', configuration: 'android-endpoints')) {
    exclude(group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5')
    exclude(group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations')
}

compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0')
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0')
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0')
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

I have tried the exclude 'support annotations' at the recyclerview and cardview, because both seem to have the module, but doesn't help in any way.

The endpoint code:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0'
appengineSdk ('com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.19'){
}

compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.19')
compile ('com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.19')
compile ('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5')
compile ('com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.1')
compile ('com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2')
compile ('com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:2.2.1'){
    exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    exclude(group: 'org.json', module: 'json')
}
```

I tried to find the conflicts with below, not sure if annotations is the correct module to search for in the first place.

```
./gradlew -q :app:dependencyInsight --dependency annotations --configuration compile
```

Results:

```
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0
 |    \--- compile
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0
 +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0
 |    +--- compile
 |    +--- com.android.support:design:22.2.0
 |    |    \--- compile
 |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
 |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.1.0
 |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
 |                   \--- compile
 +--- com.android.support:design:22.2.0 (*)
 +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0 (*)
 \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0
      +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0 (*)
      +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0
 etc
```

Comment: did you resolve this error?

Comment: any solution to this problem? I am facing this too and it's very frustrating.

Comment: I tried a lot of things, but figured out that I was calling a compile twice. It was way at the bottom so didn't see it. But yup the duplicate call created the error

Comment: What do you mean by 'compiling twice'?

Comment: @orian I was calling the same compile('...') twice, literally two lines of code exactly the same calling the same libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to systematically resolve "ZipException: duplicate entry" errors check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38675277/2107661). If you do not use multidex, just ignore the multidex part. I encountered the exact same error regarding Beta.class and resolved it by excluding all occurences of guava:

`compile ('com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }`

Comment: That actually fixed my problems!