# Android Gradle: duplicate entry : ...../Beta.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is my `build.gradle` dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'){
        exclude group:'com.android.support'
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0')
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0')
    compile ('com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.1')
    compile ('org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:3.1.0.Final')
    compile ('com.github.clans:fab:1.6.0')
    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0')
    compile ('com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1.1')
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0')
    compile ('com.android.support:design:23.0.0')
    compile ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1')
    compile ('com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4')
}
```

When I try to run my App in Android Studio I keep getting:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class
```

How can I solve this error ? any ideas ?

Btw, I tried adding:
`exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'`

Comment: remove `{
        exclude group:'com.android.support'
    }`

Comment: Did you try the accepted answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878676/transformexception-duplicate-entry-for-common-annotations-beta

Comment: This error happens when more times the same library available in your build.gradle section

Comment: yes i tired exluding guava

Comment: how can i know which thing to exclude from where ?

Comment: Are you adding any jars in your lib folder?

Comment: no im not adding any other libraries

Comment: Hey, check out my Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40938643/2107661. I do explain how to resolve issues regarding duplicate entry errors in general and how to find the libraries from which you have to exclude.