# TransformException duplicate entry for android.support.annotation.AnyRes.class

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm getting following error when tried to build project.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:  java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:android/support/annotation/AnyRes.class
```

I tried to solve with the help of link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878676/transformexception-duplicate-entry-for-common-annotations-beta), But it's not working.

My build.gradle is below

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-2.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/okio-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.9.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/easyandroidanimationslibrary.jar')

    compile project(':materialDialog')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"

}
```

I've added

> multiDexEnabled true

in defaultConfig

Comment: remove this line  "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])" ,  and then try..

Comment: Thnx its working :-)

Comment: This also worked for me but, why?