# Error creating apk, ONLY when creating signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, android-multidex, applovin

I’ve been struggling to resolve a issue, tried several options, but couldn’t solve it.

Getting issue, only when creating signed apk :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/applovin/adview/AdViewController.class

Libs structure : http://prntscr.com/ay9uam

Dependency structure :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.pollfish:pollfish:+:googleplayRelease@aar'

}
```

Note : `multiDexEnabled true` and `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` is what I need to add resolve one issue, so I've added it.
 
When I do, CMD+O(Mac) to search for `AdViewController.class`, I get : http://prntscr.com/ay9uoy

What should be my next step to resolve the issue, app runs fine for all cases (running in emulator, device..) and only at time of generating signed apk, I get above issue, which is last step of my task, I’m stuck at.

Any replies will be boon for me.

Comment: Have you used `minifyEnabled true`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like play-services already contains support-v4. Try excluding it from the classpath

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0') {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

otherwise you use this ref:
 [TransformException duplicate entry for common.annotations.Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878676/transformexception-duplicate-entry-for-common-annotations-beta)

Comment: Do you know, what and how to exclude files when added as  library in /libs folder.

I need to exclude something as error points : duplicate entry: com/applovin/adview/AdViewController.class

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve the issue.
As it was applovin class duplication, it needs to be excluded and trick was to do the following :

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'],excludes: ['applovin-sdk-6.1.5.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Hope it helps someone.